# How to click on the element with text as Continue as per the HTML through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am new to automation and stuck on click "continue" button,

```
<span class="iB button_inner">
<a href="#" data-tn-action-click="" data-tn-element="sheet-next-button" data-tn-dradis-time="1533092181465">Continue </a>
```

I have tired with XPath, ccsSelector, linkText etc. my test fails with unable to locate an element.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The format of your code example seems to be incorrect..

Comment: It's my first time posting here. I had to remove < > in order for HTML to be visible @GangaiJohann

Comment: @AaravB : I have tried with  XPath, ccsSelector, show us first which xpath ,css selector you used ?

Answer (score 0):

To invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Continue** you can use the following solution:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='iB button_inner']/a[@data-tn-element='sheet-next-button' and contains(.,'Continue')]")).click();
```

Comment: I don't get any compile error nor does my test fail, but still cannot perform click action on continue button.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Continue']"))
```

Try This if continue button has text as "Continue."

Please post your error message in case you get any.

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[contains(text(),'Continue')]
```

Try this for your object's xpath.